# Wordpress - Order by multiple meta values after date, only showing dates beyond today

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some custom fields named 'date' and 'start_time' and would like to order the posts by my custom field of 'date' and then the 'start_time'. I've got the following query - if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong that'd be great.

The query I have is below:

EDIT: The second array can be changed to anything - the field its self returns a value of anything between 0000 and 2359 - This is the value I need to sort by after the date

So I have my query returning this at the moment

Sun 26th May - Start Time: 0900
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 1300
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 2000
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 1030

But I'd like this:

Sun 26th May - Start Time: 0900
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 1030
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 1300
Sun 26th May - Start Time: 2000

```
$today = date("Ymd");
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'event',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'date',
                                'value' => $today,
                                'type' => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => '>'
                            ),
                            array(
                                  'key' => 'start_time',
                                  'value' => array( 0, 2359 ),
                                  'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                            )
                        ),
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                        'meta_key' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'ASC', 
                        'paged'=> $paged, 
                        'posts_per_page'=> 12
                    );
```

**UPDATE**

I can get it to work using an sql query :

```
<?php
                    $querystr = "
                    SELECT wposts.*
                    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
                    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
                    AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
                    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date'
                    AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'start_time'
                    AND wposts.post_type = 'event'
                    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
                    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC, wpostmeta2.meta_value ASC
                    ";$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
                ?>
<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
    <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        // STUFF 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, I can't get it to only return posts where the date is greater than today.

**Update 2:**

Returning posts where date is greater than today was simple :

```
<?php 
                                $today = date("Ymd");
                                $eventdate = get_field('date');
                            ?>
                            <?php if($eventdate > $today) : ?>
```

Comment: I remember, value is also an array.

Comment: I know that, thats why I put unsure what I put here - as I dont know :)

Comment: I can put array(0, 2359) and the compare as between, but it still doesn't sort my main issue of ordering by multiple fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a sql query - not ideal but it works

```
<?php
                    $querystr = "
                    SELECT wposts.*
                    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
                    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
                    AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
                    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date'
                    AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'start_time'
                    AND wposts.post_type = 'event'
                    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
                    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC, wpostmeta2.meta_value ASC
                    ";$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
                ?>
<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
    <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        // STUFF 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick (and awkward) way would be to change your start_time custom field to be one long number that includes the date as well as the time:

```
YYYYMMDDhhmm
```

And then, as indicated [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-sort-posts-by-a-custom-field):

```
query_posts($query_string.'&meta_key=start_time&orderby=meta_value');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try by adding date('h:i:s');

Comment: would that be to the second array? the value? if so what would the compare become?